# Shell Scripts with conditional echos

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

How do I exclude what my script is doing and only have echo's print?

For instance, i am taring a directory and I don't want every file it tar's to echo.. only the echo command.

```
#! /bin/bash 

clear

echo "Compressing the files"

cd ~/LegendaryXeo/html/
tar --exclude=".git" -cvf site.tar *
mv site.tar ~/LegendaryXeo/work/
cd ~/LegendaryXeo/work/

clear

echo "Extracting the site"

tar -xvf site.tar 

echo "Deleting Tar"

cd ~/LegendaryXeo/work/

rm -f site.tar

clear

echo "Copying files to server"

scp -r ~/LegendaryXeo/work/* user@site.com:~/../../domains/
```

Comment: If you do not want tar to emit output, why are you passing it -v?

Comment: What i'm not understand is: Why you use three steps? `tar -C ~/LegendaryXeo/html/ --exclude=".git" -cf - . | tar -C ~/LegendaryXeo/work/ -xf - && scp -r ~/LegendaryXeo/work/* user@site:~/../../domains/`. The tar part would use without the tmep tar file.  If you dont need the content of the work dir yout should do this in one step with ssh like this ``tar -C ~/LegendaryXeo/html/ --exclude=".git" -cf - . | ssh user@site "tar -C ~/../../domains/` -xf -"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect the output of `tar` to `/dev/null`:

```
tar [your options] [files] &> /dev/null
```

Any `echo` command you have in your script will still output to the screen.

Comment: I believe that is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Me too  ;) Now I just need 18 more upvotes for the reversal badge. ;)

Comment: For some reason the Tar process still echos... is this by design?

Comment: you should also redirect stderr to /dev/null